# Unexpected token while passing data to a variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

It may seem a stupid question at first, I felt so. But when I'm passing a variable which contains data with line breaks (fetched from the database) to a AJAX request, it is showing 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Here is my AJAX code:

```
$('#edit').on('click', function(){
  var post_content = '{{ $post->post_message }}';
  $.ajax({
    url: 'post/edit',
    data: {'postid': {{ $post->post_id }}, 'post_content': post_content },
    success: function(){
      alert('boom!');
    }
  });
  return false();
});
```

I'm using laravel as a framework.

I checked the developer console, and it is because of the line breaks contained in the data fetched from the database.

Comment: You should `json_encode` the message: `json_encode($post->post_message)`

Comment: `Right Click -> Inspect -> Network -> XHR` then paste the response or screen shot in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for future reference and for those who would face similar issue

So the problem I was having was the line breaks contained in the data which was fetched from the database.`json_encode($post->post_message)` solved the issue by encoding line breaks with \n.

thanks for the solution @DigitalDrifter